# check T dated files and then check if any thing is there in that file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, csh

consider todays date as 24/02/14

I have set of files in mention directory "/apps_kplus/KplusOpenReport/crs_scripts/rconvysya" and file names as

INTTRADIVBMM20142402

INTTRADIVBFX20142402

INTTRADIVBFI20142402

INTTRADIVBDE20142402

INTPOSIVBIR20142402

INTPOSIVBIR20142302

INTTRADIVBDE20142302

INTTRADIVBFI20142302

INTTRADIVBFX20142302

INTTRADIVBMM20142302

I need to find todays dated files(count will be 5 always),  and then need to check if any file is empty? So there are 2 ways.

1st check file size

2nd check word count in these files

As of now i am able to get todays dated files(count will be 5 always), How to check 2nd condition i.e. if file is empty. If file is not empty then exit 4 else exit 3.
 My code is

```
 #! /bin/bash
tm=$(date +%y%d%m)
x=$(ls /apps_kplus/KplusOpenReport/crs_scripts/rconvysya/ | grep $tm | wc -l)
if [ $x -eq 5 ]
then
exit 4
else
exit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below:

```
tm=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
count=0
loc="/apps_kplus/KplusOpenReport/crs_scripts/rconvysya/*$tm"
for f in $loc; do        
    if [ ! -s $f ]; then
        exit 3
    fi
    (( count++ ))
done

if [ $count -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 4
fi
```

Comment: can you provide me exact query. I am new to scripting.

Comment: Updated, it will exit with return code 3 if any dated files are empty or with return code 4 otherwise

Comment: Sory it is not working. I am replacing exit with echo for understanding. But even though there is no T dated file in mention folder, still query giving output as 4. I have placed a file with its size 0k in folder still output is 4.

Comment: Updated to only return 4 if all files found are non-empty